# About Data spreading in CDMA

Tags: digital-communications, digital-to-analog, digitize, code-generator

If we have data we need to transmit which is $i$, so we should multiply is using XOR function with spreading code $y$.

How many bits (Maximum and Minimum) should $i$ and $y$ can have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no lower and upper general limits, aside from the fact that you need to transmit at least 1 bit, and that your spreading sequence should be longer than 1.

By the way, you typically apply spreading to *symbols*, not *bits*.

Spreading sequences *can* be binary, but they don't *have* to be.

So, bits is the wrong unit here; symbols for $i$ would be right, and *chips* for $y$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ok noted. I watched the basic of that operation in this link, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJ81CuujwYE   .. when it says there spreading code, that can be any value ? or it's constant. For example, according to that video, if i have user #1 which is 00, I can give him any spreading code with length =4 , and then continue the process ? or that spreading code is constant for every user ?

Comment: I mean the spreading code can be generated randomly or there is a rule for generating them ?

Comment: Since we're talking about using codes to *multiplex between multiple users*: each user needs to have their own code, and the codes must be *sufficiently low in cross-correlation* so that what was meant for one user doesn't disturb what the other receives. In a perfectly synchronous system, that requirement is fulfilled by *orthogonality* (in the vector space sense); the problem is actually harder than just finding a set of orthogonal vectors: Typically, such sequences need to still be pretty orthogonal under non-perfect time synchronization, and under some frequency shift.

Comment: There's books (in fact, bookshelves, probably) on the design of CDMA systems alone, and I'm pretty sure that you won't need a high level of insight, but take away these points: 1. to perfectly separate $N$ users, you need $N$ orthogonal spreading sequences. If you understand each sequence as a vector: that's an ONB of an $N$-dimensional space. 2. Real-world systems can't be assumed to be perfectly synchronous; you can e.g. see that if you assume that any of the channel realizations used have a significant multipath, then you not only need the orthogonality (from 1), but orthogonality under

Comment: time shift. That "very small cross-correlation function for non-zero delays" property is impossible to achieve with the $N$ orthogonal sequences, so trade-offs are made. 3. same goes for any system that experiences Doppler effect and oscillator inaccuracies, i.e. frequency shifts. You need to do a trade off between sequence length (hence, 1/data speed), orthogonality under perfect sync and zero cross- and autocorrelation for zero delay.